# C# MVC get .Distinct() data

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc

I have some data in SQL Server:

```
[
  {
    "code": 1,
    "name": "qweee",
    "IDNO": "ff2222"
  },
  {
    "code": 2,
    "name": "test2",
    "IDNO": "ff2222211"
  },
  {
    "code": 3,
    "name": "fsdfasdf",
    "IDNO": "ddaaa"
  },
  {
    "code": 4,
    "name": "qweee",
    "IDNO": "ff2222"
  },
  {
    "code": 5,
    "name": "123",
    "IDNO": "U120000005"
  }
]
```

I need to use the following SQL in C # MVC

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    A1.IDNO , A1.name ,
    (SELECT COUNT(cnt_tab.IDNO) 
     FROM Postpartum_AccountsManagement AS cnt_tab
     WHERE cnt_tab.IDNO = A1.IDNO) AS data_cnt
FROM 
    Postpartum_AccountsManagement AS A1
```

Then I will get

```
[
      {
        "name": "test2",
        "IDNO": "ff2222211",
        "data_cnt": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "qweee",
        "IDNO": "ff2222",
        "data_cnt": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "fsdfasdf",
        "IDNO": "ddaaa",
        "data_cnt": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "123",
        "IDNO": "U120000005",
        "data_cnt": 1
      }
]
```

I need to get the same data in C# MVC.

Comment: OK, where is question mark?

Comment: I need to get the same data in C# MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code

Convert your json string to serialized object with NewtonSoft and use Linq query.

```
 IList<AccountsManagement> yourData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountsManagement>>(yourJsonString);

 IList<YourResult> finalResult =  yourData.GroupBy(m => new {m.Name, m.IDNO).Select(group => new YourResult(){
       Name = group.FirstOrDefault().Name,
       IDNO = group.FirstOrDefault().IDNO,
       Data_cnt = group.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Your classes will be

```
public class AccountsManagement
{
  public int Code {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string IDNO {get;set;}
}

public class YourResult
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string IDNO {get;set;}
   public int Data_cnt {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much

Comment: @Maple: Happy to hear that